# How can I pass two variables to a view?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass two variables to a view, so that I can get the data from the database.

I've tried to put both in the same line but it didn't work. And I am having this error:

> Undefined variable: utilizadores (View:
>   C:\Users\ACC\Desktop\projeto\acc\resources\views\gestaoutilizadores.blade.php)

Because it only sends the variable `$users` and then it returns the view.

This is my code:

```
public function gestaoutilizadores(){
    $users = DB::select('select * FROM `users` WHERE 1');
    return view('gestaoutilizadores',['users'=>$users]);
    $utilizadores = DB::select('select * FROM `utilizadores` WHERE 1');
    return view('gestaoutilizadores',['utilizadores'=>$utilizadores]);
}
```

How can I pass the variables `$users` and `$utilizadores` to the view?

Comment: Are you using Laravel or some other framework?

Comment: Yes I am using laravel

Comment: I've updated your tags. I removed "mysql" since the question isn't about mysql. I also added "laravel" since that is important when asking how to use the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return array with both values in it:

```
return view('gestaoutilizadores', ['utilizadores'=>$utilizadores, 'users'=>$users]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you `return` something, the function call stops there and returns what you told it to.

You need to return the data in a single array, which can be set to a variable that holds the data (makes it a little cleaner to read if you get many variables that you need to return to the view). Then return to the view with the `$data` variable as the second parameter to `view()`.

```
public function gestaoutilizadores() {
    $data = [];
    $users = DB::select('select * FROM `users` WHERE 1');
    $utilizadores = DB::select('select * FROM `utilizadores` WHERE 1');

    $data['users'] = $users;
    $data['utilizadores'] = $utilizadores;
    return view('gestaoutilizadores', $data);
}
```

Though you can also do it inline, by doing

```
public function gestaoutilizadores() {
    $users = DB::select('select * FROM `users` WHERE 1');
    $utilizadores = DB::select('select * FROM `utilizadores` WHERE 1');

    return view('gestaoutilizadores', ['users' => $users, 'utilizadores' => $utilizadores]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function gestaoutilizadores(){
    $users = DB::select('select * FROM `users` WHERE 1');

    $utilizadores = DB::select('select * FROM `utilizadores` WHERE 1');
    return view('gestaoutilizadores',['utilizadores'=>$utilizadores, 'users'=>$users]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views

You can try this

```
 gestaoutilizadores(){ 
    $users = DB::select('select * FROM users WHERE 1'); 
    $utilizadores = DB::select('select * FROM utilizadores WHERE 1'); 
    return view('gestaoutilizadores', ['utilizadores'=>$utilizadores, 'users'=>$users]); 
 }



 gestaoutilizadores(){ 
    $users = DB::select('select * FROM users WHERE 1'); 
    $utilizadores = DB::select('select * FROM utilizadores WHERE 1'); 
    return view('gestaoutilizadores', compact ('utilizadores', 'users'); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
you can use compact

```
public function gestaoutilizadores(){
    $users = DB::select('select * FROM `users` WHERE 1');
    $utilizadores = DB::select('select * FROM `utilizadores` WHERE 1');
    return view('gestaoutilizadores',compact('users', 'utilizadores'));
}
```